# ZSH with mintty on latest cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, zsh, mintty

Does anyone know how to set mintty to use zsh on the newest cygwin install?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just edit your `/etc/passwd` and replace `/bin/bash` with `/bin/zsh`.

Answer (score 10):

If your shortcut is using mintty.exe then change it to:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico /bin/zsh --login
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement David C Bishop's answer, now more likely to be using cygwin64.
(Create a Windows desktop shortcut, and paste following in as the 'location')

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico /bin/zsh --login
```